# an employee replace_employee use the same access rights and rules as parent_id (direct manager)

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, odoo, odoo-11

[image]I want the field replace_employee_id  to have the same access rights and rules as parent_id (direct manager)
I create a new object hr.delegacy (تفويض) contains( employee_id and employee_replace_id)
I add a field in  replace_employee_id in object hr.employee

```
parent_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='employee')
replace_employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='replace employee')
```

after confirm I set the value of replace_employee_id to employee_replace_id

```
 @api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
    """اعتمدت."""
    employee = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('id', '=', self.employee_id.id)])
    for delegacy in self:
        employee.replace_employee_id = delegacy.employee_replace_id
```

i want replace_employee_id  to have the same rules as parent_id in the object hr.holidays ' to see the same holidays) in the security of hr.holidays i write `['|','|',('employee_id.parent_id.user_id','=',user.id),('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id),('employee_id.parent_id','=',user.employee_ids[0].replace_employee_id.id)]"`

but it show me error in `'employee_id.parent_id','=',user.employee_ids[0].replace_employee_id.id)`

How can I correct it?

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: when i print rec.employee_id.parent_id.replace_employee_id it show me false. i add a picture in the top